# PowerShell ISE vs Script

Tags: windows, powershell

I am playing around powershell the idea is simple:

I want to verify if certain TCP port is open.

Now, I can run this as PowerShell script or I can run it in ISE.

Now, in ISE everything is fine, the script runs as supposed to.

When I run it as PowerShell Script however, I am getting error message:

---

Method invocation failed because [System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient] does not contain a method named 'ReceiveTimeout'.
At P:\checkTCP80.ps1:7 char:1
+ $tcpClient.ReceiveTimeout(5)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

---

Code:

```
$servery = gc .\servers.txt

foreach ($server in $servery) 
{
$tcpClient = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient
$tcpClient.ReceiveTimeout(5)
$tcpClient.Connect($server,80)
Write-Host ($server, $tcpClient.Connected)
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How come, that the output parameter works just fine from ISE but does not work when this is launched as a script?
2. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

According to the MS documentation on this class `ReceiveTimeout` is a property and not a method.

Try changing `$tcpClient.ReceiveTimeout(5)` to `$tcpClient.ReceiveTimeout = 5`